# Rectangle Datatrigger Fill binded to Textblock text

Tags: wpf, xaml

I would like to change the fill of a rectangle based on a Textblock text

My Textblock

```
    <TextBlock Name="lblOk" Text="OK" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Medium" />
```

My Datatrigger:

```
<Style x:Key="RectangleFill" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName="lblOk, Path=Text}" Value="OK">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF008C00" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```

My Datatrigger doesnt work, seems the Path=Text is wrong. What is the correct Path?

Comment: `"` symbol after ElementName in `ElementName="lblOk` shouldn't be there. is it a typo in question or in the real code?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code, it is working

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="RectangleFill" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lblOk, Path=Text}" Value="OK">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Name="lblOk" Text="OK" Foreground="Black" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Medium" />
        <Rectangle Width="100"
                   Height="50" Style="{StaticResource RectangleFill}">
            <Rectangle.Resources>

            </Rectangle.Resources>
        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is working. I had typo mistake as shwon in comment.

```
<Style x:Key="RectangleFill" TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Blue"></Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=lblOk, Path=Text}" Value="OK">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="#FF008C00" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
```